# React: Data rendering on second click, but not on first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, react-lifecycle

I have a modal displaying data that I'm receiving in props. When I open the modal, I should see select data displayed from my props. However, the modal is empty the first time I open it, and populates the second time.

If I go on to change the data in props, the modal stays the same on the first new click, and refreshes on the second new click.

I've tried forcing it with `setTimeout`, messing with combos of `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and other lifecycle methods, but nothing seems to work. I'm sure it has something to do with my using the `prevData` param in `componentDidMount`. But even thought react devtools shows `this.state.pricesData` updates, when I try rendering from state I get blanks every time. When I invoke a console log as a callback of setState, I get an empty array bracket in the console log (which I can expand to show all the correct array data, but I guess that's populated async after the log).

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "../../App.css";

let explanations = [];

export default class ExplanationModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pricesData: [],
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.pricesData !== prevState.pricesData) {
      return { pricesData: nextProps.pricesData };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  // to allow for async rendering
  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.pricesData !== this.state.pricesData) {
      return this.state.pricesData;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ pricesData: this.props.pricesData }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.pricesData)
    );
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevData) => {
    this.renderExp(prevData.pricesData);
  };

  renderExp = (data) => {
    explanations = [];
    data.forEach((set) =>
      explanations.push({ title: set.titel, explanation: set.explenation })
    );
  };

  onClose = () => {
    this.props.hideModal();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <div>
          {explanations.map((item) => (
            <span>
              <h4>{item.title}</h4>
              <p>{item.explanation}</p>
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onClose} className="update">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to keep your explanation array in your state. then update the state when new data arrives. because react doesn't trigger a re render if you don't update the state .

your constructor should be

```
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pricesData: [],
      explanations : []
    };
  }
```

and your renderExp function should be

```
renderExp = (data) => {
    explanations = [];
    data.forEach((set) =>
      explanations.push({ title: set.titel, explanation: set.explenation })
    );
    this.setState({ explanations })
  };
```

inside your render function

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <div>
          {this.state.explanations.map((item) => (
            <span>
              <h4>{item.title}</h4>
              <p>{item.explanation}</p>
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onClose} className="update">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way you will get the updated data when it arrives.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

The problem I think face is exceeding maximum update depth. Seeing as I'm calling `renderExp` in `componentDidMount`, and in `renderExp` I'm setting state, it gets stuck in an update/re-render loop. That's why I was saving explanations outside the class.

Any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: Follow up: called `renderExp` in `componentDidMount` using `this.state.pricesData` instead and worked a treat. Thank you!